# Select avg vote but leave out the top and bottom 5% of votes using mysql

Tags: mysql, select, average

I have a table with votes. Votes are ONLY numbers (no text, no yes/no etc).

**raw data example**

```
id   | question_id | vote
1    | 63          | 80
2    | 63          | 13
3    | 63          | 992
...
100  | 63          | 900000
101  | 63          | 5
```

I want to get the avg for a specific question but leave out the highest and lowest X% of votes (example: leave out 5% - so for every 100 votes I would avg out just 90 votes) - not by id but by max and min values of the vote number.

in the above table, 900000 and 5 would no be taken into account in the avg (assuming they are the highest and lowest votes for this question)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Do you think it will remove bias or something?

Comment: @WaleedKhan I think it _is_ a valid approach.

Comment: This might be laborious but should be easily doable if you're not afraid of subqueries.

Comment: @WaleedKhan , yes it will remove bias and people who just vote high or low numbers.

Comment: @JanDvorak love to see how this can be done... BTW, will it kill the server each time I pull something like this? thanks!

Comment: you need to avg only 80,13,992 .. is this you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This query should do the job ([see example on SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68383/16):

```
SELECT AVG(vote) FROM
(
  SELECT vote, @r:=@r+1 AS rownum
  FROM votes, (SELECT @r:=0) x
  WHERE question_id = 63
  ORDER BY vote
) x
WHERE rownum > @r * .05
  AND rownum <= @r * .95
;
```

The sub-query uses a variable to assign a rownumber to each record, the outer query removes the lowest and highest numbers.

Comment: Seems you have beat me in terms of asymptotic complexity AND code length. How come I hate those local `@variables` so much?

Comment: I doubt that I like variables more than you do, but without Analytic Functions they sometimes offer the most-readable and fastest solutions...

Comment: @PeterLang absolutely phenomenal! thanks so much. BTW does it put a strain on the server when I make this query?

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic idea that you might use:

```
SELECT AVG(vote) AS average
FROM tbl o 
WHERE question_id=?
AND (
   SELECT count(*)
   FROM tbl i
   WHERE o.question_id = i.question_id
   AND o.vote < i.vote 
)/(
   SELECT count(*)
   FROM tbl inner
   WHERE o.question_id = i.question_id
) IS BETWEEN 0.05 AND 0.95
GROUP BY question_id
```

Intuitively, the complexity is quadratic in the number of votes (unless the query executor can optimise the first subquery; the second one is easier optimise)

Some other database engines have a row number as a value that you can use in the query. This might help you achieve linear complexity.

You might be able to achieve linear complexity via multiple queries as well:

1. Query the total number of rows with the question ID.
2. Compute the position of the 5% and 95% boundaries in the sorted order.
3. Query the votes corresponding to the boundaries with a `LIMIT`. You can run two queries in parallel thanks to a `UNION`.
4. Query the average of votes knowing values the top and bottom votes.

If there are duplicate votes, you might need to replace the `vote` column by the `vote, ID` vector for the purposes of finding the boundary (this applies to both queries). The basic idea is the same.